# Python script using beautifulSoup to scrape webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the contents of the following page using BeautifulSoup,

```
<div data-referrer="pagelet_123" id="pagelet_123">
<div id="1" class="p1">
<div class="uiHeader uiHeaderTopAndBottomBorder uiHeaderSection">
<div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop">
<div>
<h4 class="uiHeaderTitle">info - 1</h4>
</div></div></div><div class="phs">
<table class="uicontenttable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="label">Other</th>
<td class="data"><div id="ua94ty_3" class="uiCollapsedList uiCollapsedListHidden uiCollapsedListNoSeparate pagesListData">
<span class="visible">
<a href="http://abc.com/Federer">info-2</a>, 
<a href="http://abc.com/pages/Ian-Wright-Out-of-Bounds/117602014955747">info-3</a>, 
<a href="http://abc.com/JuniperNetworks">info-4</a>, 
<a href="http://abc.com/pages/Join-Diaspora/118635234836351">info-5</a>
</span>
</div>
</td>
<td class="rightCol">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-referrer="pagelet_ent" id="pagelet_ent">
<div id="2" class="section2">
<div class="uiHeader uiHeaderTopAndBottomBorder uiHeaderSection">
<div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop">
<div>
<h4 class="uiHeaderTitle">info-6</h4>
</div></div></div>
<div class="phs"><table class="uiInfoTable mtm profileInfoTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="label">info - 7</th><td class="data">
<div class="mediaRowWrapper ">
<ul class="uiList uiListHorizontal clearfix pbl mediaRow">
<li class="uiListItem  uiListHorizontalItemBorder uiListHorizontalItem">
<a href="URL - 1">
<div class="mediaPortrait">
<div style="height: 75px; width: 75px;" class="fbProfileScalableThumb photo">
<img width="87.00090480941" style="margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;" title="Hans Zimmer" alt="" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203614_7170054127_6578457_s.jpg" class="img"></div><div class="mediaPageName">info - 8</div></div></a></li><li class="pls uiListItem  uiListHorizontalItemBorder uiListHorizontalItem">

<a href="URL - 2">
<div class="mediaPortrait"><div style="height: 75px; width: 75px;" class="fbProfileScalableThumb photo"><img width="87.00090480941" style="margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;" title="test" alt="" src="http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCVRllyopjA_z5F&amp;w=100&amp;h=300&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F5%2F59%2F-2.jpg&amp;fallback=hub_music&amp;prefix=s" class="img"></div><div class="mediaPageName">test</div></div></a>
</div>
<div class="mediaPageName">info - 8
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

This page contains multiple nested div's and table. need help in using BeautifulSoup to
parse only info - 1 info -2 ... info -6 and URL - 1 and URL -2.

I read BeautifulSoup's documentation, it was not much helpful. also please suggest some BeautifulSoup reference doc, book for parsing complex web pages.

Thanks for your help, appreciated!

sat

Answer (score 2):

Their documentation doesn't serve your purposes?

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

It looks to me like you're going to want something like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(theXMLAsAString)
results = soup.findAll(re.compile('info - [1-6]'))
for r in results:
    myurl = r.parent.href
```

That code isn't tested, but is the general idea of how to use BeautifulSoup.